# Salesforce Excel Connector - Windows 8, Office 2013

Tags: excel, windows8

Can't seem to get the Salesforce Excel Connector to work. Trying to access my Sandbox environment. Windows 8, Office 2013.

Each time I get the following:

"Error Generated by request::An internal server error has occurred while processing your request.
Url:https://www.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/13.0
ExceptionCode : 5103"

I've tried using 16.0, test.salesforce.com, login.salesforce.com, etc. But can't seem to get a combination to work. Tried both password and password+security token.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: got the same problem...someone?